# Syntax on inline PTX code for CUDA

Tags: cuda, ptx

As written in Nvidia's Inline PTX Assembly document, the grammar for using inline assembly is:
`asm("temp_string" : "constraint"(output) : "constraint"(input));`
Here are two examples:
`asm("vadd.s32.s32.s32 %0, %1.h0, %2.h0;" : "=r"(v) : "r"(a), "r"(b));`
`asm("vadd.u32.u32.u32 %0.b0, %1, %2, %3;" : "=r"(v) : "r"(a), "r"(b), "r"(z));`
In both examples, there are parameters such as:`h0` or `b0` follow the `%n`. I looked through CUDA's official document and didn't find anything concerns about the meaning of `h0` or `b0`. I've seen `h0`,`h1` and `b0`,`b1`,`b2`,`b3`. I guess `h0` or `h1` represents a 16bit value, while `bn` represents a byte value. Does someone know the exact meaning of these?

Thanks for the help from Roger Dahl. I read the PTX ISA 3.0 and found the answer.
"h" means half-word. `h0` means the low half-word of a 32bit word. `h1` means the high half-word of a 32bit word. "b" means an integer byte. `b0`,`b1`,`b2` and `b3` represent the first 8bit, second 8bit, third 8bit and highest 8bit of a 32bit word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vadd` is one of the video specific instructions that are included with PTX. A description of the complete PTX ISA is included with the CUDA distribution. On my machine, it's in `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v4.1\doc\ptx_isa_3.0.pdf`. The description of the `h0`, `h1`, `b0`, etc, designators are in the `8.7.11 Video Instructions` section. They represent different implicit shift/mask operations (see the `optMerge` function).

Comment: Thnks, I saw that too. Turns out I was referring to an older version online.