# Missing CUDA inline PTX constraint letter for 8 bit variables in order to disable L1 cache for 8 bit variable (bool)

Tags: cuda, inline-assembly, cpu-cache, type-constraints, ptx

**INTRODUCTION**

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553086/cuda-disable-l1-cache-only-for-one-variable) we can learn how to disable L1 cache for one single variable.
Here is the accepted answer:

> As mentioned above you can use inline PTX, here is an example:

```
__device__ __inline__ double ld_gbl_cg(const double *addr) {
  double return_value;
  asm("ld.global.cg.f64 %0, [%1];" : "=d"(return_value) : "l"(addr));
  return return_value;
}
```

> You can easily vary this by swapping .f64 for .f32 (float) or .s32
>   (int) etc., the constraint of return_value "=d" for "=d" (float) or
>   "=r" (int) etc. Note that the last constraint before (addr) - "l" -
>   denotes 64 bit addressing, if you are using 32 bit addressing, it
>   should be "r".

Now, I however, I want to load a boolean (1 byte) not a floating point. So, I thought that I could do something like this (for architecture >=sm_20):

```
__device__ inline bool ld_gbl_cg(const bool* addr){
  bool return_value;
  asm("ld.global.cg.u8 %0, [%1];" : "=???"(return_value) : "l"(addr));
  return return_value;
}
```

, where "???" should be the appropriate constraint letter for a boolean, respectively for an 8 bit unsinged integer (From [this question](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/47879), i deduced this, since it is noted that for >=sm_20, "u8" is used for a boolean). Howevever, I cannot find an appropriate constraint letter in nvidias document "[Using inline PTX Assembly in CUDA](http://mlso.hao.ucar.edu/hao/acos/sw/cuda/doc/Using_Inline_PTX_Assembly_In_CUDA.pdf)" (On page 6 are listed some constraint letters). So my question is:

**QUESTION**

1. Is there any CUDA inline PTX constraint letter for any of the types:

   - boolean
   - unsigned 8 bit integer
   - or evtl 8 bit binary variable
2. If not, what can I do in my case (explained in the introduction)? - Can the parameters "b0", "b1", etc shortly discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11546221/syntax-on-inline-ptx-code-for-cuda), be of help?

Thank you very much in advance for any help or comments!

**UPDATE**

I also need a store function reading from L2 cache instead of global memory - i.e. the **store function that is complementary to the above ld_gbl_cg function** (only once I have this function, I can completely verify that njuffa's answer works).
My best guess based on njuffa's answer below would be:

```
__device__ __forceinline__ void st_gbl_cg (const bool *addr, bool t)
{
#if defined(__LP64__) || defined(_WIN64)
    asm ("st.global.cg.u8 [%0], %1;" : "=l"(addr) : "h"((short)t));
#else
    asm ("st.global.cg.u8 [%0], %1;" : "=r"(addr) : "h"((short)t));
#endif
}
```

However, the compiler gives the warning "parameter "addr" was set but never used" and the programm fails at runtime with an "unspecified launch failure".
I also tried with .u16 instead of .u8, as I do not know to what exactly it refers. Yet the result is the same.

**(Additional information)** The following paragraph in the PTX 3.1 documentation, seems to be important for this question:

> 5.2.2 Restricted Use of Sub-Word Sizes The .u8, .s8, and .b8 instruction types are restricted to ld, st, and cvt instructions. The
>   .f16 floating-point type is allowed only in conversions to and from
>   .f32 and .f64 types. All floating-point instructions operate only on
>   .f32 and .f64 types. For convenience, ld, st, and cvt instructions
>   permit source and destination data operands to be wider than the
>   instruction-type size, so that narrow values may be loaded, stored,
>   and converted using regular-width registers. For example, 8-bit or
>   16-bit values may be held directly in 32-bit or 64-bit registers when
>   being loaded, stored, or converted to other types and sizes.

Comment: According to the [PTX ISA guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/pdf/ptx_isa_3.1.pdf) section 5.2, `.u8` is unsigned 8 bit integer.  I don't think there is a boolean built-in type.

Comment: @Robert - Thank you for your comment.
 Yes, I know that .u8 stands for 8 bit unsigned integer in PTX. What I cannot find however is the constraint letter in **CUDA inline PTX** that corresponds to a .u8 register in PTX. I.e. I do not know with what letter to replace the "???" in the above code (2nd code in the introduction). If I replace it for example with "r", I get the following error: "error: asm operand type size(1) does not match type/size implied by constraint 'r'". This error appears because r stands for a 4 byte unsigned integer, not a 1 byte unsigned integer...

Comment: The document "Using Inline PTX in CUDA" lists the available constraints. There is no constraint for byte-sized operands. This seems to make sense because there are no byte-sized registers one could bind a byte-sized variable to. Try loading into a 32-bit temporary register declared with .reg .u32, and using the "=r" constraint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the document "Using Inline PTX in CUDA", there is no constraint for byte-sized operands. Best I can tell, the closest you can get to the desired functionality is to move the data through an intermediate 'short'. This results in one additional SASS instruction for the conversion from 'short' to 'bool'.

```
__device__ __forceinline__ bool ld_gbl_cg (const bool *addr)
{
    short t;
#if defined(__LP64__) || defined(_WIN64)
    asm ("ld.global.cg.u8 %0, [%1];" : "=h"(t) : "l"(addr));
#else
    asm ("ld.global.cg.u8 %0, [%1];" : "=h"(t) : "r"(addr));
#endif
    return (bool)t;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It seems to work! (And the additional conversion should not be of importance for me :)) To know whether it definitely works, I need however the store function that is complementary to the above ld_gbl_cg function. I added this to the question above (see **UPDATE**). It would be amazing if you could help me out with this!

Comment: Loads have cache mode suffixes, I am not aware that stores have them as well. The reason your store function does not compile is because you are binding incorrectly. Both %0 and %1 are read-bindings, so addr should be bound with "l" / "r", no "=l" / "=r". You may need a "memory" clobber. I won't have time to look into the details and actually try it for the next two days.

Comment: Thank you very much for this comment. I will try a bit based on this (yet PTX is really foreign land for me). If I do not misunderstand the PTX 3.1 documentation
(http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/pdf/ptx_isa_3.1.pdf), "cache mode suffixes" do exist: Table 84, page 120 lists "Cache Operators for Memory Store Instructions".

Comment: If I use the following asm statement in the 'st_gbl_cg' function, it compiles without warnings and allows to store data to a global location (for the 64 bit address case): `asm ("st.global.cg.u8 [%0], %1;" :: "l"(addr) , "h"((short)t));`  The only thing, that I am not sure yet, is whether 'ld_gbl_cg' and 'st_gbl_cg' really act on the L2 cache rather than on global memory. In fact, using the Cache operators .cg for 'ld_gbl_cg' and 'st_gbl_cg' so far give me the same performance as using .cv (load volatile) and .wt (write through). I.e. both seem to read from the same location...

Comment: I made some test with a kernel with a loop containing a call to ld_gbl_cg and to st_gbl_cg. The time for iteration is really the same whether I use .cg for read and write or .cv (load volatile) and .wt (write through). Nevertheless, I accept the given answer above as it essentially responds to my original question. If anybody reports some experience with effects of cache operators on load store performance, I would of course be very happy...